# Sapling addon leaves of different size

Tags: modeling, sapling-addon

I am using Blender Sapling addon to generate trees. However the leaves look so alike in term of size. There is a leaf scale variation parameter but I am not sure if it varies the leaves on a tree or between different trees. I tried to change it but the results were not different much. In case it is for the size of leaves between different tree, is there any way that we can vary the leaves on tree so that they are not look so uniform?

Comment: Delete the addon-created leaves, convert the branches into a mesh (or a copy for safekeeping), add a particle system to it and use that for the leaves instead. You will also benefit from better performance and memory savings

Comment: Leaves are randomized across one tree. If raising *Leaf Scale Variation* parameter to some high value like 0.8 (up to 1) it gives random scaled leaves.

Comment: So the variation is more like randomness than what added to (or subtracted from) the real scale

Comment: It is a little different from my experience, I found that when set to 1, all the leaves become larger (not much in different size as expected) and when set to 0 they become all smaller. Can we have a good way of seeing the variation a bit clearer?